# jQuery Execute Order

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm using the following jQuery plugin and it executes when there's a click action on the specified element :

http://www.andresvidal.com/labs/relcopy.html

I also created a click function for the same element, but I expected it to execute **after** the plugin. However that isn't the case, the click function **always** executes first, thus causing problems.

Please check my code below for example, I'm new to jQuery so any suggestions / help would really be appreciated!

```
$.getScript('../js/relCopy.js', function() {

            $('#AddTable').relCopy({
                limit: 10,
                excludeSelector: '.newListSelected'
            });

$('#AddTable').click(function() {
    do something here after relcopy has finished
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event handlers are executed in the order they were bound, and since the callback from [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) executes after that script is loaded, it's binding it's `click` handler *after* yours.

So get the order you want you need to *bind* in the order you want, that means binding your click handler in the callback as well, like this:

```
$.getScript('../js/relCopy.js', function() {
  $('#AddTable').relCopy({
    limit: 10,
    excludeSelector: '.newListSelected'
  }).click(function() {
    //do something here after relcopy has finished
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly! Do you mean the callback from $.getScript() only executes after the relCopy.js has been loaded? If thats the case, shouldn't it finish executing relCopy.js before moving on to my click handler?

Comment: @user435216 - Yes for the first question, no for the second... `$.getScript()` is an asynchronous operation, it finishes when the response comes back and it executes the `success` callback then :)